# Extract raster values from nex-gddp-cmip6 bucket on amazon web service

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, raster

I am trying to extract raster values of "nex-gddp-cmip6" daily climate projections as data.frame from the amazon web service (aws). There are over 72.000 individual rasters I am interested in. These make up for more than 12TB of space which I do not have.

I downloaded 2 rasters and full list of "nex-gddp-cmip6" rasters as txt file for trial and error, wrote the following code on my laptop and it works as intended.

First, I created a data.frame to be used in loop functions to extract data sequentially and filtered for the 2 rasters:

```
V2 <- c("NEX-GDDP-CMIP6/ACCESS-CM2/historical/r1i1p1f1/pr/pr_day_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_1953.nc",
        "NEX-GDDP-CMIP6/GFDL-CM4/ssp245/r1i1p1f1/pr/pr_day_GFDL-CM4_ssp245_r1i1p1f1_gr1_2050.nc")
file <- c("pr_day_ACCESS-CM2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_1953.nc",
          "pr_day_GFDL-CM4_ssp245_r1i1p1f1_gr1_2050.nc")
cmip6_source_id <- c("ACCESS-CM2", "GFDL-CM4")
scenario <- c("historical", "ssp245")
variable <- c("pr")
year <- c("1953", "2050")
test <- data.frame(V2, file, cmip6_source_id, scenario, variable, year)
```

Then, I prepared an empty df to fill raster values. The columns "file", "cmip6_source_id", "scenario", "variable", and "year" are extracted from the test data.frame I prepared, and "x", "y" and daily values (from 1 to 366) will be extracted raster files.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=373, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "file", "cmip6_source_id", "scenario", "variable", "year", c(paste0("D",1:366)))
```

Finally, the following code does the job. I am using raster package to brick s raster, read the length of time dimension to create a new data.frame (data_df). Prepare a raster for cropping the original raster brick, cropping the raster, assign coordinates to clipped raster and extract values to data.frame. Then I join variables from test data.frame and merge with the inital data.frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster) # or library (terra)


for(file in unique(test$file)) {
  setwd("This is the directory I downloaded the raster files")
  brick <- brick(file)
  dims <- dim(brick)  #this is the raster dimensions (x,y,time)
  days <- dims[3]  #this is the length of third dimension (time) that is used to create "data_df"
  ext <- extent(25.5, 44.9, 35.8, 42.2) #extents of my clip
  clip_raster <- raster(ext, nrow = nrow(brick), ncol = ncol(brick))
  clipped <- crop(brick, clip_raster)
  brick_values <- getValues(clipped)
  brick_coords <- coordinates(clipped)
  data_df <- data.frame(coords = brick_coords, brick_values)
  names(data_df) <- c("x", "y", c(paste0("D",1:days)))
  data_df$file = file
  data_df <- data_df %>% 
    left_join(select(test, file, cmip6_source_id, scenario, variable, year), by = "file")
  df <- merge(df, data_df, all = TRUE)
}
```

This is working as intended. But as I mentioned before, there are more than 72.000 files and I do not have the resources available, so I tried to use bucket (I think thats kind of a repository) on AWS, where extra information can be found here: https://registry.opendata.aws/nex-gddp-cmip6/

I created a virtual windows server as a "free tier" on US West (Oregon) -this is where the "nex-gddp-cmip6" bucket is.
The virtual machine has specifications of (t2.micro) i386, x86_64, 1GB ram and 30gb ssd.

On the virtual machine, I wrote the following code, which does the same job. First the setup of keys and libraries:

```
library(aws.s3)
library(aws.ec2metadata)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

key <- # Substitute with your own
secret <- # Substitute with your own

Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = key,
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = secret,
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = 'us-west-2')
```

Then, the list of rasters (models), which is equivalent to test data.frame on my local machine. Then I picked a single raster from this list for testing:

```
data_list <- aws.s3::s3read_using(FUN = read.delim, sep = "", header = FALSE,
                                  object = "index_md5.txt",
                                  bucket = "nex-gddp-cmip6")
data_list$names <- sub(".*\\/", "", data_list$V2)
data_list$match <- sub("\\.nc*.", "", data_list$names)

data_list2 <- aws.s3::s3read_using(FUN = read.delim, sep = "", header = FALSE,
                                  object = "index_v1.1_md5.txt",
                                  bucket = "nex-gddp-cmip6")
data_list2$names2 <- sub(".*\\/", "", data_list2$V2)
data_list2$match <- sub("\\_v1.1.nc*.", "", data_list2$names2)

data_list3 <- data_list %>% 
  left_join(dplyr::select(data_list2, names2, match), by = "match") %>% 
  mutate(namesf = case_when(is.na(names2) ~ names,
                            TRUE ~ names2),
         version = case_when(is.na(names2) ~ "v1",
                             TRUE ~ "v1.1") ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(V2, namesf, version) %>% 
  mutate(cmip6_source_id = case_when(version == "v1" ~ str_match(namesf, "([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){4}$")[,2],
                                     TRUE ~ str_match(namesf, "([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){5}$")[,2]),
         scenario = case_when(version == "v1" ~ str_match(namesf, "([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){3}$")[,2],
                              TRUE ~ str_match(namesf, "([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){4}$")[,2]),
         variable = case_when(version == "v1" ~ str_match(namesf, "([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){6}$")[,2],
                              TRUE ~ str_match(namesf, "([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){7}$")[,2]),
         year = case_when(version == "v1" ~ str_match(namesf, "(.{4})\\.")[,2],
                          TRUE ~ str_match(namesf, "([^_]+)(?:_[^_]+){1}$")[,2]))

models <- data_list3 %>% 
  filter(scenario == "historical" | scenario == "ssp245" | scenario == "ssp585") %>% 
  rename(file = namesf)

pr_model <- models %>% 
  filter(variable == "pr")

pr_model <- pr_model[2,]
```

Finally, copied the extration code. Different from the original code, I am reading the raster from the AWS to form a brick.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=373, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "file", "cmip6_source_id", "scenario", "variable", "year", c(paste0("D",1:366)))

for(file in unique(pr_model$V2)) {
  brick <- aws.s3::s3read_using(brick,
                                object = file,
                                bucket = "nex-gddp-cmip6")  #reading the raster from AWS
  dims <- dim(brick)
  days <- dims[3]
  ext <- extent(25.5, 44.9, 35.8, 42.2)
  clip_raster <- raster(ext, nrow = nrow(brick), ncol = ncol(brick))
  clipped <- crop(brick, clip_raster)
  brick_values <- getValues(clipped)
  brick_coords <- coordinates(clipped)
  data_df <- data.frame(coords = brick_coords, brick_values)
  names(data_df) <- c("x", "y", c(paste0("D",1:days)))
  data_df$file = file
  data_df <- data_df %>% 
    left_join(select(test, file, cmip6_source_id, scenario, variable, year), by = "file")
  df <- merge(df, data_df, all = TRUE)
}
```

This works as intended until cropping the brick. Then I get the following error:

```
>   clipped <- crop(brick, clip_raster)
Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
Error in ncdf4::nc_open(x@file@name, suppress_dimvals = TRUE) : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpOOBqME\file132451ba5fa7.nc (return_on_error= FALSE )
```

I tried to create a df without cropping but also trying to get values from the brick file also gives the same error:

```
>   brick_values <- getValues(brick)
Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
Error in ncdf4::nc_open(x@file@name, suppress_dimvals = TRUE) : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpOOBqME\file132451ba5fa7.nc (return_on_error= FALSE )
```

I also tried re-reading the brick file during crop, but this did not work either:

```
clipped <- crop(aws.s3::s3read_using(brick,
                                object = file,
                                bucket = "nex-gddp-cmip6"), clip_raster)
```

I am currently out of ideas and do not know if it is the lack of machine memory or another thing. Sorry for the long post.